how to set up a collection type and other configuration for serverless opensearch via terraform?
I'm creating an open search serverless instance via terraform , see sample code below. based on the documentation, one can set collection type to , time series, search or vector search. How to do so, via terraform code?
also, in the serverless instance, is there a an automated way to ingest data, where we can select a model within sagemaker or bedrock and simply point to an s3 location where data is stored. and data get's converted to vector embeddings and pushed to opensearch serverless collection?
resource "aws_opensearchserverless_collection" "collection" {
  name = 'my_collection'
  ...
}

